# Highcharts Multi drill downs for stacked column

Tags: jquery, highcharts, stacked-chart, drilldown

A large number of examples can be found about multi level drill downs, but not for stacked columns. In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/25q3eaeo/5/) there are two stacked columns drill downs. I want to have the possibility to move from Cats in the second stacked column to a new drill down single column chart.

Does anyone have an idea to move from the second stacked column chart to a new column chart?

JavaScript:

```
    $(function() {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
          drilldown: function(e) {
            if (!e.seriesOptions) {
              var drilldowns = {
                  'animals': {
                    name: 'Cats',
                    color: '#fa7921',
                    drilldown: 'Cats',
                    data: [
                      ['2014', 10],
                      ['2015', 10],
                      ['2016', 15],
                    ]
                  }
                },
                drilldowns2 = {
                  'animals': {
                    name: 'Cows',
                    color: '#9bc53d',
                    data: [
                      ['2014', 13],
                      ['2015', 15],
                      ['2016', 15]
                    ]
                  }
                },
                drilldowns3 = {
                  'animals': {
                    name: 'Sheep',
                    color: '#e55934',
                    data: [
                      ['2014', 13],
                      ['2015', 15],
                      ['2016', 15]
                    ]
                  }
                };

              this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldowns[e.point.name]);
              this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldowns2[e.point.name]);
              this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, drilldowns3[e.point.name]);
              this.applyDrilldown();
            }
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Async drilldown'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
      },

      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          borderWidth: 0,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Cats',
        color: '#fa7921',
        data: [{
          name: 'animals',
          y: 5,
          drilldown: true
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'Cows',
        color: '#9bc53d',
        data: [{
          name: 'animals',
          y: 5,
          drilldown: true
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'Sheep',
        color: '#e55934',
        data: [{
          name: 'animals',
          y: 5,
          drilldown: true
        }]
      }],

      drilldown: {
        series: []
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/pehbcv8m/

Comment: Hi Deep 3015. This is not quite what I mean. The first drill down goes from a stack column to a stack column. After that, I want that if you click on cats for example to a new "normal" column chart (not stacked column), this would be the second drill down.

Comment: check this three level http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/xygqrupy/1/

Comment: Thank you again for your quick response. It is almost what I am looking for. First chart is a stacked column but second and third are "normal" columns. Is it possible to create a stacked column of the second graph. So eventually it becomes this: Stacked column> stacked column> "normal" column

Comment: @Deep3015 any idea?

Comment: Hi in example jsfiddle.net/deep3015/xygqrupy/1 when you click animals (which is xAxis label) it will leads to stack column (second level) and again click  cat (which is xAxis label) it will leads to normal column(third level). Yes , It is different what you have added in post. Please take idea from this and do it in your example